# Use ASP.NET MVC to Handle "Form.PHP"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, post, asp.net-mvc-routing

I was asked to write a simple POST handler for a form submission. I am using ASP.NET MVC 3. I created an ImportController with an ImportContact method, using the [HttpPost] attribute.

The trick is, I can't use /Import/ImportContact as the action. I am being forced to use form.php instead.

Is there a way to automatically redirect request to form.php to my controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an entry to your routing table that maps "form.php" to a controller/action.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Form Submit",
    "form.php",
    new { controller = "Import", action = "ImportContact" }
);
```

Comment: How can I pass along a query string?